# How to tighten SRAM HRD Rival brake lever?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram, brake-levers

I have SRAM Rival HRD brake/gear shifters on my cross bike. It's a 1X setup.

The left brake lever (this is the UK where rear brake lever is on the left, so it's the rear brake lever only) has lateral play. The shifter can be wiggled a little side to side and a little forward and backward before the brake starts to engage.

I would like to stop this play, the right hand front brake/shifter lever has no or much less noticeable play.

Firstly, I know the brake needs bleeding, and I will get this sorted but is there any way to tighten the lever?

I see from [the exploded view in the service manual](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/_4MldhWdEehFueSOZDSKDNgrkxCn4dYw2AOco-_6AxI/mtime:1501622447/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen0000000005217_hydror_rev_b.pdf) that there is a pivot pin. It doesn't appear that this can be tightened?

Is it likely that simply bleeding the system will remove some/all of the play or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was much improved by a service at a shop where they replaced the brake pad and bled the system. It seems tightening the pivot pin was not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the followup - I would not have guessed that based on the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ongoing issue with current Apex, Rival and Force HRD lever assemblies. Just found this video that details the likely cause and a relatively simple (if fiddly) fix:

Comment: Welcome to the site! In case the video you link gets taken down, could you summarize what it says, in a couple of sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Video summary: Looks like pistons get debris on their sides, and grease dries out, making them sticky (resistant to sliding) in the calipers. So bring 'em out a little bit (3mm?) and clean then grease the sides of the pistons. It's a process, but looks like it will ease pistons return back into calipers, and improve return-spring effect with smooth sliding of pistons in and out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Is this a description of the video content in the previous answer?  If so this really should be attached to that post, not on its own.  If you confirm that, we can ask to have this converted to a comment.